# Error in addTrack() trying to mux audio and video

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I'm developing an Android native app where I record the screen video stream (encoding it with the native `AMediaCodec` library to `video/avc`) and I mux it with an AAC / `audio/mp4a-latm` audio track. My code works just fine on several devices, but I got some problems with some devices (Huawei P8 and P10 lite, running Android 6.0.0 and 7.0 respectively, and Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1). The issue is that, **whenever I try to add the second track to the muxer** (no matter the order I add them), **it fails** returning a `-10000` error code.

I've *simplified* the problem, trying to just mux an audio and a video file together; the results are the same. In this simplified version I use two `AMediaExtractor`'s to get the audio and video formats to configure the `AMediaMuxer`, but when I add the second track I still get an error. Here's the code:

```
const auto videoSample = "videosample.mp4";
const auto audioSample = "audiosample.aac";
const auto filePath = "muxed_file.mp4"

auto* extractorV = AMediaExtractor_new();
AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(extractorV, videoSample);
AMediaExtractor_selectTrack(extractorV, 0U); // here I take care to select the right "video/avc" track
auto* videoFormat = AMediaExtractor_getTrackFormat(extractorV, 0U);

auto* extractorA = AMediaExtractor_new();
AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(extractorA, audioSample);
AMediaExtractor_selectTrack(extractorA, 0U); // here I take care to select the right "mp4a-latm" track
auto* audioFormat = AMediaExtractor_getTrackFormat(extractorA, 0U);

auto fd = open(filePath.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
auto* muxer = AMediaMuxer_new(fd, AMEDIAMUXER_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4);
auto videoTrack = AMediaMuxer_addTrack(muxer, videoFormat); // the operation succeeds: videoTrack is 0
auto audioTrack = AMediaMuxer_addTrack(muxer, audioFormat); // error: audioTrack is -10000

AMediaExtractor_seekTo(extractorV, 0, AMEDIAEXTRACTOR_SEEK_CLOSEST_SYNC);
AMediaExtractor_seekTo(extractorA, 0, AMEDIAEXTRACTOR_SEEK_CLOSEST_SYNC);

AMediaMuxer_start(muxer);
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Is it something that is not supposed to work on Android prior to 8 or it'a pure coincidence? I've read a lot of posts (especially by @fadden) here on SO, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Let me give you some context:

- the failure is independent from the order I add the two tracks: it will always be **the second `AMediaMuxer_addTrack()` to fail**
- audio and video tracks should be ok: **when I mux only one of the tracks, everything works well** even on Huaweis and Nexus 5, I obtain correct output files, both with the audio or video track alone
- I tried to move the `AMediaExtractor_seekTo()` calls to other positions, without success
- the same code works just fine on other devices (OnePlus 5 and Nokia 7 plus, both running Android >= 8.0)

Just for completeness, this is the code I later use to obtain the output mp4 file:

```
AMediaMuxer_start(muxer);

// mux the VIDEO track
std::array<uint8_t, 256U * 1024U> videoBuf;
AMediaCodecBufferInfo videoBufInfo{};
videoBufInfo.flags = AMediaExtractor_getSampleFlags(extractorV);
bool videoEos{};
while (!videoEos) {
    auto ts = AMediaExtractor_getSampleTime(extractorV);
    videoBufInfo.presentationTimeUs = std::max(videoBufInfo.presentationTimeUs, ts);
    videoBufInfo.size = AMediaExtractor_readSampleData(extractorV, videoBuf.data(), videoBuf.size());
    if(videoBufInfo.presentationTimeUs == -1 || videoBufInfo.size < 0) {
        videoEos = true;
    } else {
        AMediaMuxer_writeSampleData(muxer, videoTrack, videoBuf.data(), &videoBufInfo);
        AMediaExtractor_advance(extractorV);
    }
}

// mux the audio track
std::array<uint8_t, 256U * 1024U> audioBuf;
AMediaCodecBufferInfo audioBufInfo{};
audioBufInfo.flags = AMediaExtractor_getSampleFlags(extractorA);
bool audioEos{};
while (!audioEos) {
    audioBufInfo.size = AMediaExtractor_readSampleData(extractorA, audioBuf.data(), audioBuf.size());
    if(audioBufInfo.size < 0) {
        audioEos = true;
    } else {
        audioBufInfo.presentationTimeUs = AMediaExtractor_getSampleTime(extractorA);
        AMediaMuxer_writeSampleData(muxer, audioTrack, audioBuf.data(), &audioBufInfo);
        AMediaExtractor_advance(extractorA);
    }
}

AMediaMuxer_stop(muxer);
AMediaMuxer_delete(muxer);
close(fd);
AMediaFormat_delete(audioFormat);
AMediaExtractor_delete(extractorA);
AMediaFormat_delete(videoFormat);
AMediaExtractor_delete(extractorV);
```

Comment: @Paolo_M Have you solved it? I have the same issue with NdkMediaMuxer on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge plus running Android 7

Comment: @E.Abdel I came to the conclusion that, from the **native side**, this is not going to work on Android previous to 8.0 (if you have any counterexample, please let me know). It works on all devices I've tested on the Java side, though. So, I solved encoding/muxing only the video track in the native domain and then calling a Java function via JNI to mux the audio track in the Java domain.

Comment: @Paolo_M thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I came to the same conclusion, it's probably a bug. I tried to compare Android < 8.0 and 8.0 sources for hours without success